# How to Create Different frame for Images each row in listview to show images in android?

Tags: android, image, listview

I'm newbie to android development, I have to create the listview to show images,In each row i have to show varying number of image in the structure of frame. here i have tried the xml to show image views, but performance beacme poor, can you guide me to show images by programatically. i really don't know why it take much time in android. Please help me thanks in advance.

My BaseAdapter class

```
public class PostImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ViewmHdr mHdr;
        private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;
        private String videoId, titleId = "SharedWithMe";
        String User_name = "";
        int postImgCount;
        final int PM_TYPE_1 = 1, PM_TYPE_2 = 2, PM_TYPE_3 = 3;
        final int PG_TYPE_1 = 1, PG_TYPE_2 = 2;
        String url1 = "", url2 = "", url3 = "", url4 = "", url5 = "";
        private boolean isPM_3_PG_2;
        private String m_Text;
        private Context mCtxt;

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View mCtView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            if (mCtView == null) {
                mHdr = new ViewmHdr();
                mCtView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_post_new,null);
                //5 frames
                mHdr.imgVw_fr5_img1 = (ImageView) mCtView.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_fr5_img1);
                mHdr.imgVw_fr5_img2 = (ImageView) mCtView.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_fr5_img2);
                mHdr.imgVw_fr5_img3 = (ImageView) mCtView.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_fr5_img3);
                mHdr.imgVw_fr5_img4 = (ImageView) mCtView.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_fr5_img4);
                mHdr.imgVw_fr5_img5 = (ImageView) mCtView.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_fr5_img5);
                //casting remaining views
                mCtView.setTag(mHdr);
            } else {
                mHdr = (ViewmHdr) mCtView.getTag();
            }
            lHeight = mCtView.getHeight();
            //To set the Post Array values to List View
            Bean postAcc = postArrayValues.get(position);
            postImgCount = Integer.parseInt(postAcc.getImages_count());
            //Accessing image details for the particular post
            try {
                int i, j;
                for (i = 0; i < postArrayValues.size(); i++) {
                    Bean mainBean = postArrayValues.get(i);
                    int imageCOunt = Integer.parseInt(mainBean.getImages_count());
                    if (imageCOunt > 0) {
                        ArrayList<Bean> postImagesArray = mainBean.getPostImagesArray(); // get post images details like this (for first post)
                        //Accessing prost image details
                        if (postImagesArray.size() > 0) {
                            for (j = 0; j < postImagesArray.size(); j++) {
                                Bean postImgsBean = postImagesArray.get(j);
                                String imgName = postImgsBean.getPg_name();
                                String postimgName = postImgsBean.getProfile_pic();
                                try {
                                    Bean tempPostBean = postAcc.getPostImagesArray().get(j);
                                    String imgURLPost_SM = BusinessAccessLayer.IMAGE_URL + path_large + tempPostBean.getPg_name();
                                    int pg_type = Integer.valueOf(tempPostBean.getPg_type());
                                    pg_link = tempPostBean.getPg_link();
                                    String imgURLPost = tempPostBean.getPg_name();
                                    String fbVideoUrl = tempPostBean.getPg_link();

                                    //Check the Image Array count
                                    if (postImgCount > 0) {

                                        switch (pm_type) {
                                        /*PM_TYPE_1, denotes the post values from the API*/
                                            case PM_TYPE_1:
                                                switch (pg_type) {
                                                /* PM_TYPE_1,PG_TYPE_1  have Images*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_1:
                                                        mPostHideViews();

                                                        mSetImagestoPanes(j, imgURLPost_SM, imgURLPost);
                                                        break;
                                                /*PM_TYPE_1,PG_TYPE_2  have Videos*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_2:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.rL_post_video_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.rL_post_youtube_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.btnYplayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.imgVwYuthumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        videoId = extractYoutubeId(imgURLPost);
                                                        Log.e("VideoId is->", "" + videoId);
                                                        String img_url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg"; // this is link which will give u thumnail image of that video
                                                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(img_url).fit().centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVwYuthumb);
                                                        break;
                                                    default:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        break;

                                                }
                                                break;
                                        /*========PM_TYPE_1 statement Ends=======*/

                                        /*PM_TYPE_2, denotes the post values from the Facebook domain*/
                                            case PM_TYPE_2:
                                                switch (pg_type) {
                                                /* PM_TYPE_2,PG_TYPE_1  have Images*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_1:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.pFrame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgURLPost).centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVw_fr1_img1);
                                                        break;
                                                /*PM_TYPE_2,PG_TYPE_2  have Videos*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_2:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.pFrame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgURLPost).centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVw_fr1_img1);
                                                        break;
                                                    default:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        break;

                                                }
                                                break;
                                        /*========PM_TYPE_2 statement Ends=======*/

                                        /*PM_TYPE_3, denotes the post values from the Instagram domain*/
                                            case PM_TYPE_3:
                                                switch (pg_type) {
                                                /* PM_TYPE_3,PG_TYPE_1  have Images*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_1:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        mHdr.pFrame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgURLPost).centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVw_fr1_img1);
                                                        break;
                                                /*PM_TYPE_3,PG_TYPE_2  have Videos*/
                                                    case PG_TYPE_2:
                                                        isPM_3_PG_2 = true;
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        break;
                                                    default:
                                                        mPostHideViews();
                                                        break;

                                                }
                                                break;

                                        /*========PM_TYPE_3 statement Ends=======*/

                                            default:
                                                mPostHideViews();
                                                break;

                                        }

                                    } else if (postImgCount == 0) {
                                        mPostHideViews();

                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            //System.out.println("postImagesArray size is" + postImagesArray.size());
                            mPostHideViews();
                        }
                        // end of postImages loop
                        //Accessing profile image details
                    } else {
                        mPostHideViews();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

                return mCtView;
            }

        private void mSetImagestoPanes(int posOfLoop, String imgPostUrl_src, String imgPost_YoutubeUrl) throws MalformedURLException {
            String imgURLPost_SM = imgPostUrl_src;
            int j = posOfLoop;
            String url_Youtube = "";

            if (postImgCount == 1) {
                mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mHdr.pFrame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (postImgCount == 2) {
                mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mHdr.pFrame2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (j == 0) {
                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgURLPost_SM).dontAnimate().centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVw_fr2_img1);
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgURLPost_SM).dontAnimate().centerCrop().into(mHdr.imgVw_fr2_img2);
                }

            } else if (postImgCount == 3) {/*do same like previous condition else if (postImgCount == 2) visible frames*/

            } else if (postImgCount == 4) {/*do same like previous condition else if (postImgCount == 2) visible frames*/

            } else if (postImgCount == 5) {/*do same like previous condition else if (postImgCount == 2) visible frames*/

            }


        }

        private void mPostHideViews() {hidePostPanes();hidePostVideos();hidePhotoFrames();}
        private void hidePhotoFrames() {
            mHdr.pFrame1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.pFrame2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.pFrame3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.pFrame4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.pFrame5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.rL_post_fr5_more_images.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private void hidePostPanes() {
            mHdr.rL_post_video_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.wV_postVideos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.rLayout_post_Image_Pane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private void hidePostImages_5frames() {//hide frame image views
        }

        private void hidePostImages_4frames() {
           //hide frame image views
        }

        private void hidePostImages_3frames() {
           //hide frame image views
        }

        private void hidePostImages_2frames() {
            //hide frame image views
        }

        private void hidePostImages_1frames() {
           //hide frame image views
        }

        protected void hidePostVideos() {
            mHdr.btnYplayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.btnFb_player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.imgVwYuthumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.imgVw_Fb_thumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.wV_postVideos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.rL_post_fb_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHdr.rL_post_youtube_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        class ViewmHdr {
            ImageView btnYplayer, btnFb_player, imgVw_Fb_thumb, imgVwYuthumb, imgVw_profile, imgVw_share, imgVwConti, imgVwLike, imgVwCom,imgVw_fr5_img1, imgVw_fr5_img2, imgVw_fr5_img3, imgVw_fr5_img4, imgVw_fr5_img5,imgVw_fr4_img1, imgVw_fr4_img2, imgVw_fr4_img3, imgVw_fr4_img4,imgVw_fr3_img1, imgVw_fr3_img2, imgVw_fr3_img3,
,imgVw_fr4_img1, imgVw_fr4_img2, imgVw_fr4_img3, imgVw_fr4_img4 ,imgVw_fr3_img1, imgVw_fr3_img2, imgVw_fr3_img3,imgVw_fr2_img1, imgVw_fr2_img2,imgVw_fr1_img1;
            RelativeLayout rL_post_video_layout, rL_post_fb_layout, rL_post_youtube_layout, rLayout_post_Image_Pane, rL_post_fr5_more_images;
            RelativeLayout pFrame1, pFrame2, pFrame3, pFrame4, pFrame5;
            RelativeLayout layout_expand,layout_like,layout_comment,rLayout_deletepost;
            LinearLayout lL_tagging_post,lLayout_Add_Comment_Contribution;
            WebView wV_postVideos;
        }


    }
```

MyExpected OutPut 
[Present Image FirstRow of ListView Contains 5 Images, Second row Contains 1 Image. this is possible in xml, but i need optimization in listview rendering time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e1Zk.png)

Comment: this code doesn't make sens at all .... you have `for (i = 0; i < postArrayValues.size(); i++) { ...}` inside the `getView` ... and this is the main problem ... seems like you don't even know what your code is doing

Comment: ok fine bro, thank you, i will remove that logic, instead of that how can i apply new logic, please share your ideas. thanks again.

Comment: *please share your ideas.* obviously you should load images only for "current" post not for all

Comment: @Selvin i have list of post data from api, i added json data into arraylist,In baseadapter class i have reterive the data.Few post data contains image, and some of does not contains image. so i applied that logic.

Comment: @Selvin   Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Mohan please try this logic, here i created algorithm like structure for the Two Image, Its just an idea. please try for different frames of images in each row of ListView. The Code structure is below. please i need a feedback.

TwoImage.java

```
Class TwoImage extends View
{
TwoImage(Context _context)
{
uiInit()
}


Void initUi(Context _context)
{

// create object for layout inflator
    // load layout which contain two image
   // create id for image 
   imgOne = (ImageView)inflat.findviewByID(R.id.img1)
   imgTwo = (ImageView)inflat.findviewByID(R.id.img2)

}
Void loadImageToImageView(String _urlOne,string _urlTwo)
{
// Use Image Loader to load image like picasso,glide libraries

}

}

//Invoke class in Lisview adapter. i hope you're using fragment.
TowImg twoImgObj =new TwoImg(getactiviy())
// sett width and height to to
```

Thanks.

Comment: Implemented but i have doubt, l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); this is what you said "create object for layout inflator"

Comment: Please Go through android Basic, I hope it will to improve your implementation ideas.